# Upstart job cannot create directory in /var/run

Tags: permissions, upstart

I the following config in `/etc/init/foo.conf` on Ubuntu 12.04.4:

```
description "Foo"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    mkdir -p -m 0775 /var/run/foo
    chown foo:foo /var/run/foo
end script

setuid foo
setgid foo
exec /usr/local/bin/foo
```

However when this is run at boot, and when I attempt to run it manually with `sudo start foo` I get the following error in `/var/log/upstart/foo.log`:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/foo': Permission denied
```

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try first without changing user ID, let the root to make the dir. It may be the case that upstart changes the `uid` at an early stage.

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the issue. What is the correct way to get the directory created before changing the uid+gid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Upstart cookbook mentions:](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id195) ***Note*** that all processes (pre-start, post-stop, et cetera) will be run as the user specified.

As a result `mkdir` outside user's home directory will fail with permission denied results.

One solution is to create as root the directory, `chown` it for the target user and then run the executable as the user.

```
description "Foo"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    mkdir -p -m 0775 /var/run/foo
    chown foo:foo /var/run/foo
end script

exec sudo -u foo_user /usr/local/bin/foo
```

**where** `foo_user` is the target user which will initiate the executable

[Reference on how to run as different user](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user)

Comment: DANGER here: `sudo` forks when run. Now, if you check the "expect" stanza, you will see that daemons sometimes fork twice and the `expect daemon` will wait for 2 forks. Now, if you are using a daemon that forks twice, and you use `sudo` with it, there are now 3 forks (1 by sudo, 2 by the daemon) and upstart will not be able to keep track of the processes and will hang.